# android gallery with images from url folder

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I'm begginer in Android programming and I need help. How could I create an app that shows images in grid view but whenever the app is started it refreshes and loads new images from online folder?

I cant find anywhere help on internet. Everybody are giving help in loading images from specific url, for example `.../image.jpg`, but I would like images to load from `.../images/...`, and show just at specific size nad when user click it loads specific url or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a littlebit inspecific but here some resources that may help you:

Gridview:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Load Image in Android (take a look at the 2. example for storing the image locally):

http://www.whitebyte.info/android/download-and-display-image-in-android

Comment: in all this examples its needed to set a full url of 1 image then 2 image ect..but is there a way to set a folder example www.exmpl.com/images ... and app will show images from that url/folder?